# How do I create new columns based on the first occurrence in the previous group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like below

```
id   reg   version
 1   54       1
 2   54       1
 3   54       1
 4   54       2
 5   54       3
 6   54       3
 7   55       1
```

The goal is to assign two new columns previous_version and next_version that takes the values from id's and populate in previous version and the next version. In the above example df, for id = 1, since the version = 1 the next version starts from the id = 4, I populated next_version value as 4 and previous_version as null since there isn't any.

if there is no previous or next version, it should populate with null.

What I was able to achieve is to

- get the unique versions in the df.
- the first id of each version.
- Dictionary of the above 2.

I am struggling to come with a logic to apply that dictionary to the dataframe so I can populate previous_version and next_version columns.

```
versions = df['version'].unique().tolist()
version_ids = df.groupby(['reg', 'version'])['id'].first().tolist()
```

Here is how the data frame should look like

```
id   reg   version   previous_version   next_version
 1   54       1            NULL             4
 2   54       1            NUll             4
 3   54       1            NULL             4
 4   54       2            1                5
 5   54       3            4                NULL
 6   54       3            4                NULL
 7   55       1            NULL             NULL
```

What would be the best way to achieve the result if n versions are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a nested groupby, use [`Series.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), then merge.

```
def _prev_and_next_version(sf):
    # Use `Int64` to avoid conversion to float. Not crucial.
    first_id_by_version = sf.groupby('version')['id'].first().astype('Int64')
    prev = first_id_by_version.shift(1).rename('previous_version')
    next_ = first_id_by_version.shift(-1).rename('next_version')
    sf_out = sf.merge(prev, on='version').merge(next_, on='version')
    return sf_out

df.groupby('reg').apply(_prev_and_next_version).set_index(df.index)
```

Result:

```
   id  reg  version  previous_version  next_version
0   1   54        1              <NA>             4
1   2   54        1              <NA>             4
2   3   54        1              <NA>             4
3   4   54        2                 1             5
4   5   54        3                 4          <NA>
5   6   54        3                 4          <NA>
6   7   55        1              <NA>          <NA>
```

For context, `first_id_by_version` for each iteration:

```
version
1    1
2    4
3    5
Name: id, dtype: Int64

version
1    7
Name: id, dtype: Int64
```

Comment: Ensure the `reset_index` is really necessary (and would give the correct output if the groups are mixed or if the index is not a range). Maybe a `group_keys=False` or `.droplevel('reg')` would be better suited (I can't test right now).

Comment: @mozway OP didn't specify an index, so I figured it wasn't a concern. Either way, the output should be indexed the same as `df`, so a simple `.reindex(df.index)` would work, right? I'm just not sure what you mean by "if the groups are mixed".

Comment: Nevermind the comment about the mixed groups (this only applies if you assign, which is not the case here). Just use `df.groupby('reg', group_keys=False).apply(_prev_and_next_version)` and this avoid the `reset_index` ;)

Comment: @mozway I actually tried that while I was testing, but instead of index 6, there's another index 0. I suppose that's because of the nested groupby.

Comment: Yes probably, this behavior has changed recently (and is still undergoing changes), sorry about the comment

Comment: Whoops, I meant `.set_index` instead of `.reindex`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by creating a map of the combination of reg, version as key and value as id.
The series you need to use the map on are combination of reg, version + 1 and reg, version - 1.

```
k1 = list(zip(df.reg, df.version.add(1)))
k2 = list(zip(df.reg, df.version.sub(1)))
d = df.drop_duplicates(['reg', 'version'], keep='first').set_index(['reg', 'version'])['id']
df['previous_version'] = pd.Series(k2).map(d).astype('Int64')
df['next_version'] = pd.Series(k1).map(d).astype('Int64')

print(df)

   id  reg  version  previous_version  next_version
0   1   54        1              <NA>             4
1   2   54        1              <NA>             4
2   3   54        1              <NA>             4
3   4   54        2                 1             5
4   5   54        3                 4          <NA>
5   6   54        3                 4          <NA>
6   7   55        1              <NA>          <NA>
```